# MySql Syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax near '' at line 1

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax-error

**EDIT:** Apologies for the stupid question. My own lapse in concentration, plus the fact that I'm still just learning the SQL syntax kinda caused me to miss the issue.

**Original Question:** I have no clue as to what is going on here. I have tried several methods of inserting data, but none have worked so far, and I always get the same exception. I am uncertain what is causing the issue. Am I missing a command function or is there something wrong with the syntax?

```
string uName = "tess";
string uPwd = "newpassword";
int authorityLevel = 3;

try
{
    mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES(\"" + uName + "\", \"" + uPwd + "\", " + authorityLevel + ";";
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

// Output:
// You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: Use command parameter. Your code have followed bad practices.

Comment: Use placeholders .. I mean, forget about purposeful SQL injection (not really), but imagine .. *you can see the actual query cleanly* which would have made this error *easy to spot*, especially since value quotes can also be removed. I mean, just for my sanity, I always use placeholders. (But don't really forget: placeholders also *eliminate* SQL injection.)

Comment: You miss the last ) in VALUES. Answer from Abdul below is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a closing angular bracket ) at

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES(\"" + uName + "\", \"" + uPwd + "\", " + authorityLevel + ";";
```

replace this with this

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES(\"" + uName + "\", \"" + uPwd + "\", " + authorityLevel + ");";
```

And you added an extra opening angular bracket ( at

```
catch ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e)
```

replace this with

```
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, for some reason I kept missing it. However for some reason the `catch ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e)` wasn't showing an error. All good now though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parameterized queries`. It makes your code more **readable** and **secure** against sql injection attacks:

```
 mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel)  VALUES(@name,@pw,@authorityLevel)";
 mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", uName);
 mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", uPwd);
 mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorityLevel", authorityLevel);
```

Comment: Holy cow! I can see the query! (Knowing that Little Bobby isn't gonna drop the tables also makes me feel warm and fuzzy inside.)

Answer (score 1):

I Cant say anything about `C#` but your MySQL Insert syntax should like, If all columns are of string type

```
INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES('username','password','superadmin')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is simple: you are missing the `)` at the end of your Query.

Try using this instead:

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES('" + uName + "', '" + uPwd + "', '" + authorityLevel + "');";
```

Notice, that the last Parameter was also missing the quotes, and that I changed them to single-quotes.

Another Syntax-Error is at your catch-line:

```
catch ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException e)
```

You have two opening brackets - remove one of them.

Furthermore, you have to care about SQL-Injections. What, if the user enters this string to your name-field: `username'; DROP DATABASE; --`? Will it drop your database?

You should use string-escape-functions. Or *- even better-* use prepared Statement. Selman22's answer gives you an example on how to do that in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ) inyour query

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel) VALUES(\"" + uName + "\", \"" + uPwd + "\", " + authorityLevel + ");";
```

Use Parameterized Queries otherwise you will have [SQL injection Attack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
something Like this

```
String strQuery = "insert into customers (UserName, UserPassword, AuthorityLevel)  VALUES(@name,@password,@authorityLevel)"
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```